# GNOME (GDM) equivalent to LightDM's "dm-tool"

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gdm, switch-user

In my old Ubuntu 16.04 installation, I had the command

```
dm-tool switch-to-user <spouseusername>
```

mapped to <kbd>F1</kbd> so that my wife could easily jump onto her account on the family computer. Now having upgraded to 19.10 which uses GNOME, that command no longer works.

What is the equivalent CLI command on GNOME to jump into another user's session?

Comment: You can switch of tty, login, then run `startx` (W : **never** as root !!) but it would be at everyboot.

Comment: `dm-tool` is a `lightdm` utility. It's not clear for me if it's binded to `xfce4`. Could installing `lightdm` instead of `gdm3`, conserving gnome as desktop env, resolve your issue ? Notice that 19.10 doesnt prevent you to use any envirnoment you want.

Comment: @pomsky I just want a simple command string that I can use in a custom keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @B.duGaray I do not want to switch away from [whatever the current default thing is in Ubuntu these days]. I just want to add a shortcut to what I already have, and I believe I need a CLI command for that shortcut.

Comment: @pomsky - I am looking for a one-key solution (it's for my *wife!*) and I find it hard to believe that the good old GDM does not have a thing that little LightDM offers. I'm no Linux guru but I thought that Linux made "everything" possible, so I am still hopeful.

Comment: @pomsky - How do I map "ctrl-alt-del" to the "F1" key? To answer your question, no that is not sufficient, it's a workaround at best. I am surprised that GDM does not offer a switch-user command.

Comment: Of course it's a workaround, they're not always like-for-like replacement of each other. Also did you try what I *actually* suggested? I said nothing about "ctrl-alt-**del**".

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun if you see the system menu.. you have the "switch user" button/menu item and when you click that it takes you to GDM login screen where you can select the user to login. This can be achieved with a direct command as a keyboard shortcut. In 16.04 what is the case? by pressing F1 she sees her desktop? or she needs to enter pw?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the GDM greeter by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> without logging out the current user. From there it's quite intuitive to login as another user.

To mimic this from the command-line you can use `xdotool`. First install it by running

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Then the following would mimic the aforementioned key-combination

```
xdotool key ctrl+alt+F1
```

You can assign this command to the <kbd>F1</kbd> key in the 'keyboard shortcuts' option in *Settings*.

Comment: Thank you for describing a workaround. I am still holding on to the hope of discovering an actual user-switch command like the one in LightDM.

Comment: Sure, I also hope there's something simpler.